# How to make CMake to generate KDE-style makefiles with progress tracking?

Tags: cmake, build-automation, kde-plasma

```
Generating moc_krvfshandler.cpp
[  2%] [  2%] Building CXX object krusader/GUI/CMakeFiles/GUI.dir/GUI_automoc.o
Building CXX object krusader/DiskUsage/CMakeFiles/DiskUsage.dir/DiskUsage_automoc.o
[  2%] Building CXX object krusader/Dialogs/CMakeFiles/Dialogs.dir/Dialogs_automoc.o
Generating moc_krmousehandler.cpp
[  3%] Building CXX object krusader/ActionMan/CMakeFiles/ActionMan.dir/actionman.o
Generating moc_packjob.cpp
[  4%] Building CXX object krusader/Dialogs/CMakeFiles/Dialogs.dir/krsqueezedtextlabel.o
Generating moc_krpreviews.cpp
[  4%] Built target VFS_automoc
[  4%] Generating moc_krvfsmodel.cpp
```

Wanted the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CMake docs this is the [`RULE_MESSAGES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_global%3aRULE_MESSAGES) property and its `ON`by default and only works for `Makefile` based targets.